# meta tage for SEO

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are meta keywords worth the effort?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-meta-keywords-worth-the-effort)

Are the metatags importent for Search engines?

Answer (score 2):

They used to be, but today they hardly are. Google ignores them completely and focuses more on the content of the page, and on the content of the links linking to you site.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of metatag you are talking about:

meta keywords: this tag is useless, googlebot doesn´t even bother with it.
meta description: google uses this tag to create the snippet (text around your link) shown in SERPs.
meta title: google uses this tag to create the snippet (link title) shown in SERPs and is a must-have for ranking criteria.
meta robots: if you set this tag to "noindex,nofollow" Googlebot will honor it, and won't index of follow any page that includes this meta.