# Is the meta tag for keywords not useful anymore?

Tags: seo, keywords, meta-keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are meta keywords worth the effort?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-meta-keywords-worth-the-effort)

I am not a SEO expert, I just know the very basics. Today I read an [article](http://www.seo-watch.com/html/meta_name_keywords.php) and I am confused.

If the metatag for keywords is not useful anymore:

1. Where should we place our keyword list?
2. What alternatives exist?

I read [googles beginers guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) for SEO, but it says nothing about it.

Comment: I hope [this article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) will be helpful

Comment: I know that Google doesn't use them, I don't know about any other search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Google no longer uses meta keywords as a ranking factor whatsoever, and I doubt any other SEs do either.

> Where should we place our keyword list?

You shouldn't have one, you should just write relevant, decent copy :)

Comment: What if my site is a single page site with just a button and a textfield ?

Comment: Then you're not going to rank for anything, unless you have correct page title text and a load of backlinks for authorative sites with supporting anchor-text.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should we place our keyword list?

Nowhere. Write good quality content that uses your keywords instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you know that [Google no longer uses the keyword meta tag](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/). [Nor do the others](http://searchengineland.com/yahoo-search-no-longer-uses-meta-keywords-tag-27303).

The next thing you need to understand (to answer Q1) is that ***it's not your keyword list***. No, it's your (potential) visitor's keyword list. People will find your content using a number of different keywords and keyword combinations, including misspellings, synonyms etc. *So get over thinking you can control how people find your content*.

What are you're alternatives? Well, that you do have some control over. Ensuring that your page's title contains your (most important) keyword or phrase, that your keyword/phrase is in your headings/emphasis tags on your page, contained within your body copy etc. Equally important is that the links from your own, and other sites, that link to that page, contain the keyword/phrase in the anchor text of the back-links.

Remember, each page should only be relevant to a core keyword/phrase - there's nothing to be gained from trying to bundle them all in to all your pages or your home-page. ***ANYTHING*** you do to try and **manipulate** how search engines view/rank your site/pages, will end up costing you in the long run.

So: Write Naturally on a single topic, per page.

If your page is simply a button and a textfield - *why* should it deserve to rank? Unless your backlinks to that page can overcome your 'on-page' content issues.

Answer (score 1):

Google do not use meta keywords. Google use only title and description of the site.