# Is HTML meta element effective to increase a site's search ranking?

Tags: html, seo, search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do meta keywords have any impact on ranking algorithms?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/do-meta-keywords-have-any-impact-on-ranking-algorithms)

Some sites and web developers say that meta keywords and meta description is not important and necessary to increase search ranking of a site or to be indexed while some are say reverse. Only important thing is putting sitemap.xml file to site's root ,some say. Is meta element important for search ranking?

Answer (score 1):

Meta element still important in website building, even if Google doesn't care about meta keywords, other spiders do. Meta description still important for every search engines. Don't focus only on Google. Web is not google.