# Is there any lyrics meta tag when a page contains lyrics?

Tags: seo, meta-description, meta-keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do meta keywords have any impact on ranking algorithms?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/do-meta-keywords-have-any-impact-on-ranking-algorithms)

So I created a website for a friend that has a music band and for each song we have the lyrics for it. I don't want to use the word `lyrics` (if it's not necessary) because it is pretty obvious when you're visiting the site.

So my question is what should I do, from my side, to let the crawlers know that when somebody is searching for [`the smallest creature reboot lyrics`](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20smallest%20creature%20reboot%20lyrics) his official website will appear higher? Any SEO tricks for music, bands, lyrics, etc, before the whole planet is going to start linking to his website? :)

Comment: @toomanyairmiles well... I'm not using meta tags at all so my question is more like.. what can I do instead.. because of the fact that many robots are ignoring them..

Comment: @JohnConde.. how this is like an exact duplicate.. did you even read the question?! Maybe meta tag wasn't the right term to use.. but I was looking for any SEO trick that could help it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put the word lyrics in the page title at the least. This is rarely given notice by users when they are on the site, however it is frequently used by search engines in the search results page.

- It won't impact user experience when on the site
- It will enhance user experience when searching for the site
- It will let Google know the page contains lyrics

It's a win any way you slice it.

Comment: Yes.. that's sounds like a really cool idea actually..

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any reference to anywhere where Google will rank official sites higher than normal sites, or any special tricks for lyrics. You might be interested in [schema.org for audio files](http://schema.org/AudioObject), though: it's a special way to get Google and other search engines to include data about your song, such as the length and the title of it, in search results.

You also might be interested in [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)