# Is there any pros and cons of duplication content of meta description tag to keyword tag

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description, meta-keywords

On a Huge Website we have no time to add `keywords` manually so I'm same phrases for `Description` and `keyword` like this

```
<meta name='description' content="Hello how are you?">
<meta name='keywords' content="Hello how are you?">
```

Is there any pros and cons to do this for site's SEO

Answer (score 1):

There are no pros, because Search Engines don't pay any attention to them: [Do meta keywords have any impact on ranking algorithms?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/do-meta-keywords-have-any-impact-on-ranking-algorithms?rq=1)

I wouldn't bother if I were you.

Comment: I don't agree. Don't get me wrong, I feel it used to be important, but over the past 6 months I've seen the majority of websites on page 1 DO now include the meta tags. I'm not saying this is a rule, but I would not rule this out any longer.

Comment: @paulmorriss - If I'm duplicating Meta description content to Keyword content, can it improve the Density of Keywords? http://www.irkawebpromotions.com/keywords-optimization/4-keywords-tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove all meta keywords if I were you. Quoting [seomoz.org](http://www.seomoz.org/):

> Search engines have, for years, ignored the meta keywords tag as a
>   ranking signal. Although it technically does not harm rankings, it can
>   be used by competitors as a method to extract your targeted terms and
>   thus, we recommend against its use.

Answer (score 0):

Meta description can be very useful to increase your Click Through Rate, however is apparently doesn't help ranking higher or lower.

In some cases, you would prefer Google to automatically generate your SERP snippets, but in some others you would like to specify it yourself with meta Description (although it is not always picked by Google). You could also have a look at Open Directory Project description (and use the flag NOODP in case you do not want that).

So, in short, it depends on the nature of your website. If you have a long list of products with no content, I'd go for generating a meta description for every page. If you have a Q&A sort of site (like SE), you probably don't want meta description.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, never duplicate content at any part of your website where ever possible (of course unless relevant)! And keep it relevant to the page. don't confuse Google by using irrelevant meta tags and remember, the tags should describe the page, not give just a general overview in the site.

IMO, meta tags are helping now - they used to be key, then were ignored and recently I'm seeing the value of them increase. Some will disagree, to those I say Google something! Type in brown shoes into Google and see what ratio use meta tags to those which don't! Don't get me wrong, until 6 months ago, I didn't use them either, but my goodness I wouldn't do a site now without.

With bigger sites, I stuck the meta tags into the database (depends on your structure of course) which saved me time. However, if ranking high is important, I would suggest finding the time for this.